# Attaching event with window.open()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a billing system using codeigniter - mysql. I would like to print invoice using `window.open()` of JavaScript . My code is like below

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{

function invoice()
{
    var wind = window.open('','_blank','width=700,height=700,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');

    var html = '<input type="button" id="submit_button" value="Submit"/>';
    $(wind.document.body).html(html);
}

$('#print_invoice').click(invoice);
});
```

I would like to attach a function in the input button `id="submit_button"` to save the invoice in database.

Could any one say how can I do that?

Comment: Use a form and a submit button?

Comment: If you just want an event handler, why dont you write the script and add it to the new html?

Comment: @ryadavilli -- I would like to click the button to print and save the invoice in database. I attached alert() to it .But nothing happens when I click the button.
Thanks for reply.

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, but you are opening a new window with a print button, and on click of that button, you want the script in your first/parent window to perform the print.

Comment: @ryadavili -- I am opening a new window with a print button and  other information on that new window when I am clicking the button(**#print_invoice**). I would like to print that new window and save that information in database.
Thanks For reply.